# Roccat Ryos MK Pro macro manager sets random delay

Tags: last-chaos

I'm trying to create a macro, which hits one key and then sets a delay of e.g. one hour. So I create the macro like this:

[image]

When I save it and then reopen the macro manager, it looks like this:

[image]

I thought this looks like the maximum delay number, so it should always reset to this delay when I enter a number which is greater than 61.056. So I tried this:

[image]

But when I now save it and reopen the macro manager it looks like this:

[image]

It looks like roccat macro manager just sets a random delay there. Is there a maximum delay? Am I not able to add a delay of one hour?

I'm using the latest driver version, downloaded from the official roccat website. My keyboard is a Roccat Ryos MK Pro keyboard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, but this game isn't very popular anymore, there is no tag. It's a fantasy MMORPG. Thanks for the hint with gamedev.

Comment: what's the game called? I'll tag it for you. If this is actually a game's UI, then my bad on the GameDev suggestion. It looked like some kind of software.

Comment: It's called "Last Chaos". Mostly played in Germany. Thx :)

Answer (score -1):

The waiting times are 16bit values in hardware, so this should limit you to 65535 milliseconds per wait. Maybe you would like to add 60 down/up events of an unused key with 60000 msec waits after each.

Comment: Hmm okay this could be one workaround, even if it's very ugly imo. I don't understand why roccat is not allowing any delay number. I'll give it a try, thx.